# iOS 15 Live Text - detect close action

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios15

How can I detect closing Live Text "keyboard" (top right close button) and moving to regular keyboard?

I trigger live text start like this:

```
textField.becomeFirstResponder()
textField.delegate = self
textField.captureTextFromCamera(self.textField)
```

Then in `shouldChangeCharactersIn` I have some text modifications/filtering input data:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let finalArray = string.components(separatedBy: " ").map({ $0.cleanString() })
    if let foundedText = finalArray.first(where: { $0.count == 8 && $0.isAlphanumeric }) {
        textField.text = foundedText
        textField.endEditing(true)
        textField.delegate = nil
    }
    return false // I must return false when Live Text keyboard presented and return true when regular keyboard presented
}
```

But when I close live text keyboard I can not edit text inside textfield because in delegate I have `return false`. I need to set `textfield.delegate = nil` when Live Text keyboard will be closed.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this ?

Comment: @Leena no, we have simplified our logic in that place in app. Looks like there are no APIs for this functionality yet:(